# How to dismiss keyboard on scroll

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo, getstream-io

I am use Stream feed. When I tap on StatusUpdateForm it open keyboard. But now I cannot dismiss it unless I post update.

How to dismiss StatusUpdateForm when user start scroll on FlatFeed?

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}} forceInset={{ top: 'always' }}>
        <StreamApp
          apiKey={key}
          appId={id}
          token={token}
        >
          <FlatFeed Activity={CustomActivity} />
          <StatusUpdateForm feedGroup="timeline" />
        </StreamApp>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
};
```

export default App;

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the particular library that you are using, but it likely wraps a ScrollView for the feed. If so, you can use the [keyboardDismissMode](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#keyboarddismissmode) prop - `on-drag` works on both platforms and `interactive` just works on iOS.